# setState Cannot Update During Existing State Transition Despite Correct Syntax

Tags: react-native, render, state, setstate

I have been banging my head against the wall attempting to correct any syntactical errors within my code, but I continue to get the "setState Cannot Update During Existing State" Error. I have made reference to similar threads, but the answers didn't really seem to apply to my situation well enough (or solution failed me).

Here is the code that I have targeted as having the problem:

```
getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            searching: false,
        anim: new Animated.Value(305),
            user: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
        }
    },
render: function() {
   return <View>
     <View style={styles.mainView}>
        { this.renderProperElement() }
     </View>
}, 
renderProperElement: function() {
        var that = this;
        return <Animated.View
                style={[styles.searchWrapper, {transform: [{translateX: this.state.anim}]}]}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.icon}  onPress={that.startSearch()}>
                    <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../img/search.png')} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TextInput style={styles.searchInput} autoFocus = {true} />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={that.stopSearch()} style={styles.icon}>
                    <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../img/cancel.png')} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
    },
    startSearch: function() {
        this.setState({ searching: true });

        Animated.timing(
             this.state.anim,
             {
                 toValue: 0,
                 easing: Easing.elastic(1),
             }
        ).start();
    },
    stopSearch: function() {
        Animated.timing(
             this.state.anim,
             {
                 toValue: 305,
                 easing: Easing.elastic(1),
             }
        ).start();
    },
```

In particular, the code singles out the call of the function in render and the startSearch function here:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have set your state to searching:true when you first pressed touchable opacity, but you never had changed that state on stop search method, so you better again change the searching state to false in stop search method as:

```
        this.setState({ searching: false });
```

so, when you again set this searching state, your application will result your required condition.

This error might be occured due to attempt to change state condition with the same value as previous.

Comment: are you referring to the startSearch function? If so, I do have the state set to  true there

Comment: oh - i see - yeah I changed that as well but no luck unfortunately

Comment: else try setting like this:   this.setState({searching: !searching}); for both cases.

Comment: i think the problem is the setstate change itself - RN tends not to like state changes triggered by render - but I am not sure any alternative function to this

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here (although React now warns me that I am binding a component method to the component and that RN does this for me automatically (which it did not).

Read more: http://4dev.tech/2016/03/reactjs-error-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transition-such-as-within-render-render-methods-should-be-a-pure-function-of-props-and-state/